# How is "Kernel" in a Pure Math sense related to "Kernel" in a Statistics sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm trying to learn about Support Vector Machines with its "kernel methods" and "kernel trick", and my pure math background seems to be getting in the way, as I suspect that what they mean by kernel is not what I think of it as meaning.

I'm used to a kernel being related to a homomorphism and being the "stuff" that gets mapped to 0 in the Image, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra).

I'm seeing kernel used in Artificial Intelligence and Statistics contexts more like it is here: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform".

Are the two senses of the word "kernel" linked at all, or is it just an unfortunate word-reuse with completely separate meanings?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680006/306553 Related

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel are related to each other